# Overlapping images R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am preparing a R markdown document. I am reading many images from a directory to the .rmd document. I can do this fine with a loop, however, the images overlap and cut-off small amounts of each which is rather annoying.

My code:

````
```{r , results='asis', echo=FALSE}
files <- list.files(path = "/images/, pattern = "png", full.names = TRUE)

for (f in files) {
    cat(paste0("![](", f, ")\n"))

}
```
````

This returns all the png's in the directory `images` but they are overlapped. I tried adding a blank line, i.e:

````
```{r , results='asis', echo=FALSE}
files <- list.files(path = "/images/, pattern = "png", full.names = TRUE)

for (f in files) {
    cat(paste0("![](", f, ")\n"))
print("")
}
```
````

But this doesn't fix it.

Comment: Have you tried to set the size ?

Answer (score 0):

No need of even looping through files, taking advantage of the vectorized `paste0`. Try this

````
```{r , results='asis', echo=FALSE}
files <- list.files(path = "/images/, pattern = "png", full.names = TRUE)  
res <- paste0("![](", files, ")<br><br>")
cat(res)
```
````

you can add remove the number of `<br>` for additional vertical space

Comment: The code itself doesn't work but I just needed the `<br>`, thanks.